# Is it a bad practice to store my user's ObjectId in a JWT in the sub claim?

Tags: account-security, jwt

Is it a bad practice to store my user's ObjectId in a JWT in the sub claim?
I could create an alternate UUID field in the user database and use this instead, but I wondered if I should?

I use this sub claim in both the refreshToken and accessToken.

Comment: It's not ideal, but I wouldn't bother about it, as long as it's not any PII or otherwise 'useful' information for an attacker or otherwise bad actor. If you are worried about security, then I suggest that you encrypt the JWT: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519#appendix-A.1 If the question is about whether or not the 'sub' claim is the correct place for it, then as long as the Id is unique, it's totally fine. But you NEED to at least use a strong signing algorithm, and make sure that the signature algorithm is properly verified, and cannot be replaced with 'None'.

Comment: ...which could be used to inject an arbitrary ObjectId.

Comment: Yes, I've tested none and verify correctly. What do you recommend I use for encryption? I'm using nodejs. Thx.

Comment: I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47720701/how-to-generate-and-validate-jwe-in-node-js/47919929

Comment: Or search for node js "JWE".